# Windows Desktop GUI Automation using Python - Sleep vs tight loop

Tags: python, windows, ui-automation, pyautogui

I am using PyAutoGUI library of Python to automate GUI. The application which I am automating opens a new window after I am done with data entry on my current window. Everything is taken care by python automation (data entry in my current window and the click required to open the window).

When the click is performed in the current window, the new window takes some time to open (which may range from 2 - 5 seconds). So there are two options that I can think of here:

1. Sleep using `time.sleep(5)` (Con: 3 seconds might be wasted unnecessarily)
2. Spin in a tight loop till the window appears on the screen. PyAutoGUI offers a `locateOnScreen` function which could be used to find out if the window has actually appeared on the screen. (However, this is CPU intensive and the function itself is CPU intensive and takes almost 2 seconds to return)

So it looks [1] is a better option to me. Is there some other technique that I may have missed that would be better than either of these two methods? Thanks.

Comment: Option 1 is the way to go

Comment: Either one is wrong. You'll have to use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx), and [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373868.aspx) to get notifications for windows that are created/destroyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows only GUI automation [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) is a bit more full-featured (and pythonic). It waits some default time implicitly and allows explicit waiting (some CPU-non-intensive loop is inside: kind of 0.1 sec pause and quick check for changes, then waiting again).

PyAutoGUI `locateOnScreen` function uses advanced analysis of the screenshot. That is why it's so CPU intensive (but cross-platform).

pywinauto example:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="win32").start(u'your_app.exe')
app.MainWindow.menu_select(u'File->Open')

app.OpenDialog.Edit.set_edit_text(u'some path')
app.OpenDialog.Open.click()
app.OpenDialog.wait_not('visible', timeout=10)

new_main_window = app.window(title_re='^.* - The Software$')
new_main_window.wait('ready', timeout=15)
```

[Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) is a good starting point for learning pywinauto core concept.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and kudos/respect for the excellent `pywinauto` library!! However I see some stuff are not working as expected for me. For example, when I try `app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.TypeKeys("hello")` in the console, all I get is "hello" printed on the console instead of on the Notepad that I had opened using `pywinauto`. I am using python version 3.4.3 and pywinauto version 0.5.4

Comment: Well, this looks like this happens only when I have multiple unsaved notepads open at the same time.

Comment: We all need to say thanks to Mark who made such a cool library. We're just trying to extend it. BTW, the `TypeKeys` method should set focus to the target window automatically. Or you may do `app.UntitledNotepad.SetFocus()` explicitly.

Comment: Bingo! That was it. I had to do that explicitly for some reason. Really cool work, guys. Good to see a general purpose scripting language evolving in desktop automation and competing with the likes of AutoHotkey and Autoit.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a discussion about future [multi-backend interface](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/129). We also need a pure Python solution for OS X (no good ideas yet). Any help would be useful.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, Thanks for the great work.. how does pywinauto and pyautogui compare to sikuli and autopy?

Comment: We have no detailed comparison, but sikuli/pyautogui are based on image recognition while pywinauto is fully text based using different UI access technologies. This allows flexible timings and not so CPU intensive like finding an image.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `pyautogui.getAllWindows()`. This function returns all windows and their handles. so you can check when the new window has been added. for example:

```
windows = pyautogui.getAllWindows()
windows_count = len(windows)
while True:
    current_windows = pyautogui.getAllWindows()
    if len(current_windows) != windows_count:
        break
```

Also, you can use the handle number of the desired window to activate the desired window and bring it to the foreground:

```
desired_window = pyautogui.Window(#enter window handle number)
desired_window.activate()
```

another way that I think is easier is `pyautogui.getActiveWindowTitle()`. This function returns the title of the active window. Maybe you can use that for break condition.

```
while True:
    title=pyautogui.getActiveWindowTitle()
    if title== "your desired window's title":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option one but I would sleep for 2 seconds if that is the minimum average time required the open a window. After 2 seconds, I would check if the window has appeared and if not, then I would sleep again for 2 seconds. That would possibly save more time than sleeping for 5 seconds.

But since trying to check for the window is CPU intensive and time consuming, I think waiting for 5 seconds would be better over all.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with sleeping for 2 seconds is that, without a window drawn yet, the rest of the automation code (that is supposed to execute on the new windos) executes causing unexpected results like other background windows being minimized or closing some other background window.

Comment: My response was not clear and I also didn't take into consideration that the function to locate window is cpu intensive. You're right, waiting for 5 seconds is the better approach.