# better way to automate mouse&keyboard using pyautogui

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

I wrote a script using `pyautogui` that should start an program (an IDE) and then start using it.
This is the script so far:

```
#! python3
# mouseNow.py - Displays the mouse cursor's current position.
import pyautogui, sys, subprocess
from time import sleep

x,y = 1100,550

subprocess.call([r'C:\...exe',  arg1, arg2])
pyautogui.click(x,y)
sleep(5) # 2 sec should suffice but this is for safety
pyautogui.typewrite(my_string)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

This works well but I want to be portable. The `x,y` values were determined by where the program prompt appears on screen after I start the program, but this is not portable, I think. Is there a way to point the mouse to the prompt without giving const parameters? something like `move_mouse_to_window_of_this_process_after_starting_it()`

Also, I use `sleep()` so I would write the data to the window *after* it appears, but I guess it's not a good way (some PC will run this much slower, I guess), so is there a way to know when the prompt appeared and then do the `pyautogui.typewrite(my_string)`?

**EDIT:** I found a simple solution for the `move_mouse_to_window_of_this_process_after_starting_it()`
:

`>>> pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need portable and reliable solution, you have to find a library that supports accessibility technologies to access GUI elements by text. Basic technologies are:

- Win32 API, MS UI Automation (Windows)
- AT-SPI (Linux)
- Apple Accessibility API (MacOS)

There are several open-source GUI automation libraries supporting some of these technologies (usually 1 or 2). Python solutions:

- [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) on Windows (both Win32 API & MS UIA, see [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html))
- [pyatspi2](https://github.com/GNOME/pyatspi2) on Linux
- [pyatom](https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom) on MacOS

There is also [a thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361728/3648361) regarding hard sleeps vs flexible waiting.

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are interacting with the .exe excludes alternatives to coordinates or blind firing (Tab, Tab, Enter etc..).

If the application has an API, you could interact with it programatically. 
If it doesn't you can only try to match the location for x screen resolutions, and this only if the GUI is used in Fullscreen/windowed Fullscreen.

Comment: is there another way of interacting with .exe files that won't exclude alternatives?